# How to select the "Justify text" toggle button in TinyMCE by default?

Tags: javascript, extjs, configuration, tinymce, togglebutton

My application is written using Ext.js and uses TinyMCE. The toolbars in the TinyMCE editors offers text alignment options: align left, center, right and justify. I would like the "justify" option to be selected by default when the screen containing the editor is loaded. I looked in the docs of TinyMCE and Ext.js to no avail.

Here my configuration code for TinyMCE:

```
Ext.define('Xxx.config.TinyMceConfig',{
    singleton : true,
    alternateClassName : ['TinyMceConfig'],
    config:{
        plugins: [
            "lists link charmap searchreplace code fullscreen table paste ice"
        ],
        language : "fr_FR",
        docs_language : "fr_FR",
        visual : true,
        cleanup_on_startup : false,
        cleanup : true,
        gecko_spellcheck : true,
        remove_linebreaks : false,
        encoding : "xml",
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        toolbar1 : "fullscreen | undo redo selectall | bold italic underline  alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | pastetext pasteword pasteEditor",
        toolbar2 : "searchreplace | subscript superscript charmap | unlink removeformat | visualaid table | cleanup code ice_smartquotes",
        toolbar3 : "bullist numlist row_props cell_props | row_before row_after delete_row | col_before col_after delete_col | ice_togglechanges ice_toggleshowchanges iceacceptall icerejectall iceaccept icereject",

        inline_styles : false,
        paste_as_text :true,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
        paste_text_use_dialog: true,
        paste_retain_style_properties: "margin, border, border-width, border-style, bgcolor, background, border-color, ul, li, ol, page-break-before, " +
            " page-break-after, border-collapse, padding, width, height, font-size, font-weight, font-family, text-align, text-decoration, float, " +
            "display, line-height, align",
        paste_convert_headers_to_strong : true,
        paste_convert_word_fake_lists: false,
        ice: {
            isForceTracking: false,
            isTracking: false,
            user: { name: 'Utilisateur inconnu', id: 1}
        },

        menubar:false,
        statusbar: false,
        elementpath: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small'
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use tinymce property forced_root_block_attrs, and forcing style in line text-align justify

```
config:{
  ...,
  forced_root_block_attrs : { style: 'text-align: justify;' }
}
```

tinymce docs:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block_attrs